# Can you run javascript as a dynamic language in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

...without waiting for compilation (i.e. "Build").

Note:  By dynamic I mean that this creates a variable immediately after I hit enter without any delay.

```
var x = 1;
```

I current use chrome dev tools to write dynamic java script, but I'd prefer to use visual studio if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify JavaScript save and refresh your browser.

JavaScript is interpreted in your browser not visual studio.

You can't debug JavaScript in visual studio as far as I am aware.

Comment: Too bad!  I think the VS IDE would be an improvement over the browser.

Comment: Chrome has an awesome debugger. Test it out. In fact look for a YouTube video. Its great.